# GCC совсем непонятная ошибка при компиляции

Tags: c, gcc

В заголовке есть такой код:

```
typedef enum
{
    serCOM1,
    serCOM2,
    serCOM3,
    serCOM4
} eCOMPort;
```

Ничего необычного. GCC выдает ошибку

> `error: storage class specified for parameter 'eCOMPort'`

С чем может быть связано? Вообще не пойму. Аналогично с `typedef struct`-ами.

Comment: Довольно странно для компилятора языка Си (в котором нет классов), выдавать ошибку связанную с классами. Может вы компилируете не gcc, а g++? Покажите строку компиляции.

Comment: Это может быть, в случае если перед объявлениями typedef включается заголовок, в котором есть ошибки (забыта открывающая или закрывающая скобка и т.п.).

Comment: Ваш пример успешно компилируется: https://gist.github.com/907224

Comment: Ошибка не связана с классами. `storage class` - определяет как хранить переменные (auto, static, extern...).

Comment: Точно, ок, фейл.

Comment: Код в вопросе выдран из контекста, что делает вопрос бессмысленным. Присутствие слова "параметр" в сообщении об ошибке однозначно указывает на это.

Answer (score 1):

Натолкнул на мысль комментарий **cool**. Только включены выше заголовки только стандартных библиотек. В *них* и вылезла куча ошибок. А связано это с тем, что кодировка проекта UTF-8, а хидеров стандартной библиотеки - ANSI. Отсюда вроде и грабли. Перекодирую.

Отсюда следующий вопрос. Как обойти данную проблему, оставив кодировку проекта UTF-8(Doxygen блоки на русском)(или как в кодировке ANSI использовать русский в Doxygen).

Comment: Эм.. Но ведь в стандартных библиотеках кириллицы нет, а в таком случае ansi неотличимо от utf8.

Answer (score 0):

я обычно пишу так

```
enum eCOMPort
{
serCOM1,
serCOM2,
serCOM3,
serCOM4
};

eCOMPort port;
```

и т.д.
все работает нормально...

Comment: А не должно. В отличие от C++, в C необходимо указывать enum при объявлении переменной этого типа.

Comment: Вот тоже склоняюсь к этому варианту. Проверю

Comment: В таком случае
error: expected declaration specifiers before 'eCOMPort'
Т.к. eCOMPort не является типом данных.

Comment: прошу пардону, не заострился на том что компилятор сишный. Конечно же мой вариант для ц++.

Answer (score 0):

Может, Вы где-нибудь неправильно используете перечисление или его значения?

Comment: Использую правильно. До тех мест где используется это перечисление компиляция не доходит.

Answer (score 0):

Уберите typedef.

```
enum
{
    serCOM1,
    serCOM2,
    serCOM3,
    serCOM4
} eCOMPort;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/3S4cwX